# Alt-Tab->Is Ready

Tags: gnome-shell, 18.10

Frequently when I hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, it doesn't actually change to the last window, it just displays a notification that this particular window "is ready". If I hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> again, it switches.

This happens just randomly all the time.

I am using Wayland

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

How can I figure out what is doing this?

Comment: It does seem as if it's Chrome. I've tried running just Firefox now and I can't recreate it.

Comment: @DKBose I am using Wayland

Comment: @DKBose Here's a screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/mVNS5eD

Comment: @DKBose I assume sloppy focus, since I need to click on stuff to change focus.

Comment: @DKBose I actually did use the StealMyFocus extension, but I've disabled it

Comment: If you disable **all** your gnome-extensions, log out, and log back in does the problem persist?

Comment: I've been looking at this a bit more and I get the feeling it's a Wayland issue. If you can reproducibly demonstrate the issue on a pristine Ubuntu 18.10 running Wayland, it maybe worth filing a bug.